# Using memcached on a high end web application

Tags: php, memcached, scalability

We are developing a high end web application with php/mysql and would like to explore more into memcached usage.

From the tutorials we understand that we need to write to memcached server along with writing to mysql tables. But we are confused how to use this if we are loading a list of data with a pagination. In that page we might need to filter data based on different fields. In this scenario, can we rely on memcached along without using mysql database. If not, how can memcached help to scale php application.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, memcached does not persist your data to the disk, so relying on it to keep your data is not a good practice

memcached helps to scale your php application by minimizing the load from your db by serving results from queries or even better minimizing the load off the web server by storing the entire html if you can (there are actually many good use cases for memcached)

consider the follwing flow:
1. client browsing to your page
2. php application requests the data from memcached by a key (the key can be the sql query, the url ... it depends)
3. if memcached has the data use it
4. if not the php application should query the data from mysql
5. after the data is retrieved save it in memcached so next request it will be available in 2

to handle updates, make sure to define ttl to each item you store in the memcached (of course there are also other ways to invalidate the cache)